# cacheAsBitmap on a scaled MovieClip holding a Bitmap - performance boost?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash, bitmapdata

Say I have a 300x300 BitmapData.
And say I have a MovieClip 'mc' holding a Bitmap with that BitmapData.

If mc's scale is 0.5, it means that on every one of mc's draw requests the inner Bitmap will have to scale its BitmapData, right?

So applying mc.cacheAsBitmap=true might improve performance because the mc will create a Cached Bitmap of its scaled content, thus saving the work of its inner Bitmap on every draw request.

Am I right?

Thanks for the help

Eyal

Answer (score 0):

Caching that movie clip as bitmap will create a new bitmap data in memory and you won't need to calculate it's pixel data every time, so yes, it will boost performance.

But to be completely honest - you won't even notice it. It's usually used to transform vector graphics to pixel data (raster). Such small transformations like scale or translation don't take so much to process.

Comment: CMagic thanks for answering, but how does BitmapData Scaling not considered to be a performance hit? in my perhaps naive approach to Image Scaling it feels pretty intense :)  perhaps I should post a new question in this matter? ... thannks again... Eyal.